# xamarin plug and play architecture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I need to create a application which would take the preference of the user when starting the application for the first time and then the appropriate module would be downloaded for the application. Is it possible using xamarin.forms?
Currently we are using xamarin.forms PCL project and creating app for android and iOS using xamarin.forms.

Comment: This is very vague. Please show us what you have tried so far. Also what does 'appropriate module' mean? What kind of module are you talking about?

Comment: We have not started the coding but were trying to find out how to achieve this for our product. In our product there would be a common sign on module in the mobile application which would allow the user to select a range of products. Once the user signs on and selects the application that is needed by the user, according to the selection the necessary modules would be downloaded and appended to the original sign on application.

Comment: So, multiple users would download the same sign on application but according to their selection different modules are loaded. Hence, we do not have to download all the modules for all the users and the size of the application would not be too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not, though you'd likely be tied to Android. Dynamic execution on iOS is not supported, and I'm not sure about Windows. It should be an easy enough test: click a button, download an assembly from somewhere, dynamically load it, then instantiate a class that implements an interface you're looking for. I've been wanting to do a blog post on this very thing, but alas...

Another option which may be iOS compatible is having some code in JavaScript, then download and run it in a WebView. Though that may be more trouble than it's worth.